# findFragmentById or findFragmentByTag for PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, preferenceactivity, preferencefragment

I have a PreferenceActivity that add PreferenceFragment via Headers:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
...

@Override
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
    loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
}
...
}
```

Now I need to call a method of PreferenceFragment from PreferenceActivity but I can't use `Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("tagfragment");` because using Headers to add PreferenceFragment I don't know the TAG or the ID assigned to the fragment.

How can I solve?

[SOLVED]

Solved using this method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18005721/570488

Comment: Why not using a PreferenceFragment + an iterface to handle the comunication? I did that recently.

Comment: I've usually used interface to comunicate from fragment to activity. But I need to comunicate from activity to fragment.

Comment: I see... in that case try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348078/how-do-i-access-preferencefragment-by-id

Comment: uhm...it's not very clear: in which part of my PreferenceActivity I should write that code?? what's R.id.pref_sharing??? the id of my fragment is what I'm looking for. And finally I don't need the String name of the fragment (that I can have simply with EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT) but the Fragment object.

Comment: That id is probably the fragment container id. Anyway try run this code http://pastebin.com/QGTqjNkT after the load of the whole preferenceActivity and check the log. Try find out the preferenceFragment with that.

Comment: I've tried to call fragmentFetcher() in onResume, onActivityForResult and onPause but getListAdapter() is alway null

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the PreferenceActivity is already loaded when you call this:

```
MyPreferenceFragment frag = (MyPreferenceFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
```

MyPreferenceFragment should be replaced for your own PreferenceFragment class name.

Comment: same problem: frag is null. To better understand I'm trying tu use in-app billing from a PreferenceFragment using the second method of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14131852/570488
So from PreferenceActivity I need to call:

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("YourTag");       
    if (fragment != null)
    {
        ((MyFragmentWithIabHelper)fragment).onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode,data);
    }

But I don't know the id or the tag of the PreferenceFragment...

Comment: did you try     android.R.id.content as i said on answer?

Comment: that id points to the root view of the activity which in your case should be the PreferenceFragment, right? so instead findFragmentByTag use findFragmentById

Comment: Sure, I've used findFragmentById(android.R.id.content); as posted by you but it returns null.

Comment: Weird because it returns me the correct PreferenceFragment.